# RxJava2 dispose part of the stream

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I have implemented following behavior:

1. Presenter observes UI for event
2. UI event triggers asynchronous operation
3. After asynchronous operation finishes, result is set to ViewModel.
4. ViewModel is emitted to View to update state

This results in unidirectional data flow - which is easy to manage.

ViewModel and Presenter survive orientation change, state is not lost.

My implementation:

Presenter:

```
public class Presenter {
    private final MainViewModel viewModel = new MainViewModel();
    private final Interactor interactor;
    private final CompositeDisposable viewDisposables = new CompositeDisposable();
    private MainActivity view;

    public Presenter(Interactor interactor) {
        this.interactor = interactor;
    }

    void onCreateView(MainActivity view) {
        this.view = view;
        viewDisposables.addAll(onGetResult(), listenToViewModelUpdates());
    }

    void onDestroyView() {
        viewDisposables.clear();
        view = null;
    }

    private Disposable onGetResult() {
        return view.clickObservable()
                .flatMap(__ -> Observable.fromCallable(interactor::doWork)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()))
                .subscribe(result -> {
                    viewModel.result = result;
                    viewModel.sendUpdate();
                });
    }

    private Disposable listenToViewModelUpdates() {
        return viewModel.observe().subscribe(viewModel -> view.update(viewModel));
    }

}
```

This implementation works fine, it is connected as one stream.
But there is a bug in this code. During configuration change, result of asynchronous operation is lost, because stream inside flatMap is being disposed with outer stream.

Would it be possible to keep Observable inside flatMap alive while unsubscribing from view Observable? In other words, only dispose upstream of flatMap?

I have created separate streams, one for async tasks and other for observing the view, it fits all my requirements, but it seems to be unclean design.

Comment: Doesn't configuration change really mean that you're no longer insterested in whatever the result of a downstream operation is?

Comment: No, I need to preserve that task in the background and retrieve result of the operation anyways. For ex. you want to finish payment, and you rotate your screen, you need to be notified about result of the payment operation otherwise you won't know what actually happend. That operation cannot be duplicated.

Comment: In this case, I think your payment should be independent observable, not a flatmapped one. See if this link can help: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3930

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have actually implemented that as separate stream and it worked well. I just wanted to make sure there isn't better way to do it.

Comment: I would expect that separate stream imlementation is the better way, considering your setup. Maybe you don't need it separated for all types of events, but for that particular one you've described it's definitely that.